# Unicode special characters conversion

Tags: python, swift, unicode, special-characters

I made a dictionary of type `[String: [String]]`. The values represent a list of names, while the key represents the starting Letter of all of these names. Got it?

Okay. Now I can append names to their key-array through an algorithm which detects their first letter. This is where my problem starts. I would like to put names which start with special character for example `"Ø"` into the `"O"-key-array`.

Something like this:

`"Øder"` -----> Algorithm which detects first letter ------> `["0": ["Øder", ...]]`

My approach was to convert the first letter to their Unicode and check if it is an special character and convert it to their related latin letter.

Is this the way to go, or are their simpler solutions I did not consider?

Comment: Why did you tag the question for both Python and Swift?

Comment: also, are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: In Python you can use [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to convert a character to its nearest ASCII equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well in Swift:

```
let names = ["test", "another", "two", "øder"]

let index = names.reduce([Character: [String]]()) {
  (var initial: [Character: [String]], current: String) -> [Character: [String]] in
  if let first = current.characters.first
    where initial[first]?.append(current) == nil {
      initial[first] = [current]
  }

  return initial
}

print(index) // -> ["ø": ["øder"], "t": ["test", "two"], "a": ["another"]]
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any functions that translate unicode characters to a simpler ASCII form. Perhaps some sort of dictionary can be created with such mappings.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Of course it can be refined to better deal with upper and lower case, symbols, Unicode glyphs, and the like.